# wxTextCtrl OSX mutated vowel

Tags: unicode, wxwidgets, multibyte

i am using wxMac 2.8 in non-unicode build. I try to read a file with mutated vowels "ü" to a wxtextctrl. When i do, the data gets interpreted as current encoding, but it is a multibyte string. I narrowed the problem down to this:

```
text_ctrl->Clear();
text_ctrl->SetValue("üüüäääööößßß");
```

This is the result:

√º√º√º√§√§√§√∂√∂√∂√ü√ü√ü

Note that the character count has doubled - printing the string in gdb displays "\303\274" and similar per original char. Typing "ü" or similar into the textctrl is no problem. I tried various wxMBConv methods but the result is always the same. Is there a way to solve this?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use anything but 7 bit ASCII, you *must* use Unicode build of wxWidgets. Just do yourself a favour and switch to it. If you have too much existing code that was written for "ANSI" build of wxWidgets 2.8 and earlier and doesn't compile with Unicode build, use wxWidgets 2.9 instead where it will compile -- and work as intended.

Comment: This is good advice, but *must* is a bit overblown.  If you are stuck with an 8-bit wxWidgets, you can still get things right.  Just make sure that everything is converted to utf-8 of wide-strings as soon as you get the data.  (Also I don't think the OP is using an ANSI build on her Mac).

Comment: The question explicitly says "non-unicode" and I don't see what else could it mean but "ANSI". Also, it's true that in theory you might be able to make everything work in ANSI build, especially if you can change the locale under which you're running (e.g. to ensure it uses UTF-8), but this is so hard to do in practice that I'd strongly advise forgetting about theory here and doing the sensible thing instead.

Comment: We will switch to wx 3.0 soon anyway, but i need a hotfix here. So for my particular problem, since it is a single spot in a large application using wx 2.8 successfully, is it possible to send the text input to the Carbon/Cocoa textctrl directly using Carbon/Cocoa commnands inside an #ifdef?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your text editor (for program source code) is in a different encoding from the running program.

Suppose for example that your text entry control and the rest of your program are (correctly) using UTF-8.  Now if your text editor is using some other encoding, then a string that looks fine on screen will actually contain garbage bytes.

Assuming you are in a position to help create a pure-UTF8 world, then you should:

1) Encode UTF-8 directly into the string literals using escapes, e.g. "\303" or "\xc3".  That's annoying to do, but it means you just don't have to worry about you text editor (or the editor settings of other developers).

2) Then check that the program is using UTF-8 everywhere.